# Calling a variable in Matlab without using the full name?

Tags: matlab, variables, filenames

I am creating a script to be universal in opening pre-made Data files that hold the same basic information, but the original files are not consistent in how they are named.

An example, the same variable has 3 different variants in the different files:

Data01.SubData

Data01.SubData_01

Data01.SubData01

Is there a way to ask Matlab to look for and call any variables that start with "Data01.SubData" regardless of the the final characters in the name? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean to "call" a variable? Anyway, it's usually bad practice to have so many variables with similar names. Better pack them up in a cell array or a struct

Comment: What are the file formats? How are they organized within the folder structure(1 file per folder)?

Comment: I completely agree about the bad practice in naming convention, but I am unfortunately forced to deal with them as they are given to me. 

To clarify. It is a .mat file with a structure array. The script is supposed to work for all .mat files and I just change the name within load(' ') to open each one. 

The structure is then organized as follows:

Comment: Data.Object01.SubData 


Data.Object02.SubData 


etc...     


or


Data.Object01.SubData01 


Data.Object02.SubData02 


etc...    


or


Data.Object01.SubData_01 


Data.Object02.SubData_02 


etc...   

Apologies about the formatting, first time posting and didn't quite get the hang of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `fieldnames` to get a list of names, do your matching, then grab the field you want:

```
f = fieldnames(Data01);
match = regexp(f, '^SubData.*');
fieldnum = find(~cellfun(@isempty, match));
subdata = Data01.(f{fieldnum});
```

If the confusion is at the top level rather than at the substruct level, you can do the same thing by loading your .mat file into another struct, rather than dumping the variables directly into the workspace: `mydata = load('somefile.mat');`